# how to raise specific events at a specific time intervals using timers

Tags: c#, timer

```
timer1.interval=10000;
timer1.enabled=true;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//have to raise multiple events at a specific time interval
}
```

> have to raise events at a time intervals 2000 4000 6000 8000

Comment: then set your interval to 2000...?  I don't understand what you're asking

Comment: i have to perform different tasks at the each time span 0f 2000

Answer (score 0):

Set your interval to 2000, add the EventHandler to the Tick, check if there are listeners to the events you want to raise, if yes, raise the event with the Arguments you want.

```
   timer1.interval=2000;
    timer1.enabled=true;
    timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timer1.Start();

    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(YourEvent!=null)
                     YourEvent(this,YourEventArgs);
            }
```